# How to download Tortoise SVN 'Show Log' info into a file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to download Tortoise SVN 'Show Log' info into a file (I need revision no, author, date, message and modified files list).  What is the easiest way to do this?  If this is not possible with Tortoise SVN, what is the appropriate SVN command to do that or is there any tool which does this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

This is a built-in feature of TortoiseSVN:

1. Right click the folder and choose the "Show Log" command
2. Shift-click all of the revisions you need
3. Right-click and choose "Copy to clipboard"

Then, just paste into your favorite text editor.

Answer (score 13):

Or use command line:

```
svn log -v > branch.log
```

Comment: Use below option if you suspect a huge log  `-l [--limit] ARG         : maximum number of log entries`